# How to fill diagonal in fabricjs

Tags: fabricjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xAjv.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2TTJ.png)

I am using Fabricjs. It's version is 2.4.5.

I want to fill diagonal line both side at different time.

Right Striped Diagonal :

https://i.hizliresim.com/P1My55.png

Left Striped Diagonal :

https://i.hizliresim.com/JZ20pQ.png

I tried like this fill each 0.01 white and black. But i could not set diagonal. My code is working, if image height big.

The higher the polygon height, the more horizontal the lines are.

```js
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
let points = [
 {x: 0, y: 0},
  {x: 300, y: 0},
 {x: 300, y: 350},
 {x: 0, y: 350}
];

let polygon = new fabric.Polygon(points, {
  fill : 'white',
  stroke : 'black',
  strokeWidth : 5,
  selectable: true,
  objectCaching: false,
  lockScalingX: true,
  lockScalingY: true,
  lockMovementX: true,
  lockMovementY: true,
  lockRotation: true
});

let colorStops = {};
for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  let key = (i / 100);
  colorStops[key] = i % 2 === 0 ? "black" : "white";
}

polygon.setGradient('fill', {
  x1: -polygon.width,
  y1: -polygon.height,
  x2: polygon.width,
  y2: polygon.height,
  colorStops: colorStops
});
    
canvas.add(polygon);
canvas.renderAll();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.5/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600" class="canvas"></canvas>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k7d9taxL/)

Comment: jfyi, the 2 images you linked seem to be inaccessible (403 forbidden). If you can't inline them, please upload to imgur.com or some such.

Comment: @shkaper updated.